# how to combine three columns and remove duplicates in sql

Tags: mysql

I have table with 7 columns where I want to combine three column and want to remove duplicates. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to update the table `SERIAL_NUMBERS` with just a single row of combined `warranty_indicator, account, date_sold` data. If that's true then I will suggest the following.

1. Duplicate `SERIAL_NUMBERS` table:

```
   CREATE TABLE SERIAL_NUMBERS_NEW LIKE SERIAL_NUMBERS;
```

2. Add unique constraint - combination of `warranty_indicator, account, date_sold`:

```
   ALTER TABLE SERIAL_NUMBERS_NEW
    ADD CONSTRAINT Index1 UNIQUE (warranty_indicator,account,date_sold);
```

3. Insert data from `SERIAL_NUMBERS` table to `SERIAL_NUMBERS_NEW` using INSERT IGNORE ; to ignore duplicates:

```
   INSERT IGNORE INTO SERIAL_NUMBERS_NEW 
    SELECT * FROM SERIAL_NUMBERS;
```

4. Rename old and new table:

```
   RENAME TABLE SERIAL_NUMBERS TO SERIAL_NUMBERS_OLD;
   RENAME TABLE SERIAL_NUMBERS_NEW TO SERIAL_NUMBERS;
```

5. Check data:

```
   SELECT * FROM SERIAL_NUMBERS_OLD;
   SELECT * FROM SERIAL_NUMBERS;
```

Keep in mind that any future data inserted will treat duplicates according to the unique constraint. Therefore, if you have program running the `INSERT` syntax, make sure you update it to `INSERT IGNORE`.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77b1750fad124e79e3b3826d2781881f)

Comment: Thank you very much for putting the efforts i appreciate. I have updated mu queswtion with examples. I have followed your way but having an error here is the error `ALTER TABLE duplicate ADD CONSTRAINT INDEX1 UNIQUE(col1,col2,col3) Error Code: 1170. BLOB/TEXT column 'col2' used in key specification without a key length`

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE duplicate;` and post into your question. Thanks